# Title of fantasy trilogy: priestess possessed by spider demon?

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to find the title of a book/series written approximately 20-30 years ago, and I can't remember the author.

The series involved a young nobleman/prince who fell for a girl who had travelled to his fathers kingdom/estate. She was accompanied by a priestess. On their travels to some other place, the priestess becomes possessed by a demon who had transformed itself into a spider and crawled down the throat of the priestess.

The demon is fomenting war in the kingdoms and somehow manages to trap the young girl in some kind do underworld where the young man travels to try and save her. At the same time there is some kind of demon god trying to destroy or take over the kingdom/countries and there is the epic banding together of enemies of my enemy kind of theme.

Does anyone recognize the series and/or who author may have been? Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is "The books of the Kingdoms" trilogy by Angus Wells.
[image]

Blurb text from the back covers of the books:

> The First book of the Kingdoms:
> WRATH of ASHAR
> HE WAS BORN IN THE FLAMES OF A FIRE BEYOND
> IMAGINING, UNTOUCHED AS ALL AROUND HIM
> THE GREAT FOREST BLACKENED AND SHRIVELLED
> IN THE FLAMES...TAWS THE MERCILESS!
> It is a time of prophecies fulfilled, as a mysterious being with
> terrifying powers comes forth from an inferno to unite the
> warring barbarian tribes of the North against the Three
> Kingdoms: Tamur, Kesh and Ust-Galich. Hope for the
> Kingdoms lies in the birth of Kedryn Caitin, whom the Holy
> Sisterhood of Kyrie believe to be the champion whose
> coming is foretold in their sacred book. But Taws also
> knows of the boy's existence, and as his armies cut a bloody
> swath across the peaceful land , Kedryn and his kin come
> ever nearer his merciless grasp...
> ISBN 0-7221-9026-3
> Sphere Books Limited, 1988

> The Second book of the Kingdoms:
> THE USURPER
> THE BATTLE WAS OVER. KEDRYN CAITIN HAD LED
> THE THREE KINGDOMS TO VICTORY OVER THE
> BARABRIAN HORDES. IT SHOULD HAVE BEEN A
> TIME OF PEACY….
> But Taws was not defeated. He who was spawned in the cold
> fires of Ashar swore vengeance that with his dark sorceries
> the Three Kingdoms would fall.
> As for Kedryn, the Chosen prophesied in the sacred book of
> the Sisterhood, he was blind. His sight had been stolen by a
> bewitched sword. He must seek the shamans of the
> Barbarians. Only with their help cold he enter the
> netherworld to confront the shade of the warrior who in life
> had wielded the blade.
> While Kedryn travelled far, accompanied only by his loyal
> friend and a holy Sister, Taws the Messenger saw his
> opportunity. With the Chosen absent, he would use his
> terrifying magicks to gain the throne of the Kingdoms by one
> dark means or another…
> ISBN: 0-7474-0262-0
> Sphere Books Limited, 1989

> The Third book of the Kingdoms:
> THE WAY BENEATH
> TAWS THE MESSENGER IS DEFEATED AND THE
> THREE KINGDOMS AT LAST KNOW PEACE. KEDRYN
> CAITIN, THE CHOSEN OF KYRIE, IS HAILED HIGH
> KING.  AT HIS SIDE HIS NEW-WON BRIDE, WYNETT.
> BUT DEEP WITHIN THE REALMS OF THE
> NETHERWORLD THE GOD, ASHAR, PLANS A
> TERRIBLE REVENGE...
> All Kedryn has fought  so hard to build stands in jeopardy
> when the Lord of Fire unleashes leviathan on the world to
> take Wynett for is own, living bait in a demonic trap.
> To win back his love Kedryn must enter the world of
> ghosts, to claim the hell-forged blade wielded by the long-
> dead Drul, ancient overlord of the barbarian hordes. Only
> that dreadful sword may prevail against the awful power
> of the vengeance-bent god, and to save Wynett from
> damnation eternal Kedryn must brave the perils of the
> god's domain — must face Ashar himself in battle for his
> very soul…
> ISBN: 0-7474-0263-9
> Sphere Books Limited, 1990

Comment: Thankyou soooo much for answering the question it has been driving me nuts trying to remember but once I saw your answer the title/author and all came back.... so again much appreciated.

Comment: @Mogsy These have been sitting on a book shelve in my study for 25 years. I had completely forgotten about them until I saw your question. Thank you for reminding me. I'm going to re-read them too :-)